# Sencha touch application performance improvement tips

Tags: html, cordova, sencha-touch, mobile-website, sencha-touch-2

How to improve performance of Sencha Touch based application ? After spending couple of days I found that the performance is really gone bad after the application becomes bit heavy. Any suggestions or tips that could help to improve its performance and to get it to a better shape is highly appreciated.

Also, My application  usages phone-gap for native binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important thing you should be doing is making sure your DOM is as lean as possible. If you have a panel/container that is not currently visible, remove / destroy it.

```
panel.destroy()
parentPanel.remove(destory)
```